# Historical price per minute between two timestamps for a cryptocurrency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cryptocurrency

I am successfully using the following code to output the price per minute for historical price data ranging back a couple of hours:

```
import requests
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def minute_price_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol, limit, aggregate, exchange=''):
    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym={}&tsym={}&limit={}&aggregate={}'\
        .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper(), limit, aggregate)
    if exchange:
        url += '&e={}'.format(exchange)
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = page.json()['Data']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
    return df

time_delta = 1 # Bar width in minutes
df = minute_price_historical('BTC', 'USD', 9999, time_delta)
print('Max length = %s' % len(df))
print('Max time = %s' % (df.timestamp.max() - df.timestamp.min()))

plt.plot(df.timestamp, df.close)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Thumbs up to the Cryptocompare API guys.

Ultimately, I would like to achieve the following:

1) Output the price per minute between two timestamps, e.g. 3/12/18 3.00pm (15.00) and 3/12/18 3.30pm (15.30)

2) I would like to save this data into 3 columns "Token"(in the case above BTC), "Timestamp", "Price" as a csv or json ideally

Anyone with an idea or two on how to do that with the given code or an alternative approach?

Comment: Is this Java or Python? It sure doesn't look like Java code to me

Comment: I added Java as a hashtag since I wasn't sure if there was a Java solution already ready to go somewhere. I'd be happy either way, but would prefer to learn from extending the given code. If you were the one downvoting the question because you didn't like the hashtag, please remove it. That's just plain silly

Comment: It may be wise to keep your question specific to a single language, else it risks being closed for being too broad.

Comment: k, that makes sense. Thanks for pointing that out, I will remove the hashtag.

Comment: what are "Coin" and "Price"? they are not in df when I run your script. Btw, there is an indentation error in your function

Comment: Token is the more accurate term, e.g. Bitcoin (BTC)(that's the one in the code above) or Ethereum (ETH). The price column should reflect the price for a given timestamp, let's say $8120 for timestamp 3/12/18 3.22pm. In short: The token is BTC in the df and the price is USD (price in USD).

Comment: I think I fixed the indentation error

Comment: @FatTwin ok I see better, but still, in your df you have 4 columns seeming to have a "Price", they are named "close " ,   "high"  ,   "low"     and "open". Which one do you want in your column price? perfect for the indentation correction ;)

Comment: @Ben.T "close" is the one, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so to answer the first part, you can create two timestamp min and max for the interval you want:

```
time_min = pd.Timestamp('2018-05-26 15:00')
time_max = pd.Timestamp('2018-05-26 15:30')
```

and then create a `mask` to select only the rows of your `df` between this two times:

```
mask = (df.timestamp >= time_min) & (df.timestamp <= time_max)
```

Now if you do `df[mask]` you will get only the rows where the timestamp is within this 30 min window.

For the second question:

```
# you can first create the column for the token do:
df['token'] = 'BTC' # should fill all the rows of your df with this word
# rename the column close to price
df = df.rename(columns={'close':'price'})
# finally save as csv only the columns you want:
df[['token','timestamp','price']].to_csv('here_the_path_to_your/file.csv')
```

and if you want to add the mask, then do

```
df[['token','timestamp','price']][mask].to_csv('here_the_path_to_your/file.csv')
```

EDIT for the json, it depends how you want it, so I would suggest to read the [documentation about to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) to find what is possible

Comment: Thanks!!! I am fairly new to Python, so please bear with me. When I add the first part of the code, I got an error prompt. Please see the code added to the bottom of my question

Comment: @FatTwin if you want that your function return only the data between the two timestamps, then it's `return df[mask]` and then `df = minute_price_historical('BTC', 'USD', 9999, time_delta)` will contain only the data between the two timestamps. Note that in python if you define a variable (here `mask` e.g.) in a function that you don't return, it's not known outside so when you do `df[mask] = ...` it does not know `mask` at this moment of the code :)

Comment: @FatTwin otherwise, all the code I wrote in my anwser, I would put it just after `df = minute_price_historical('BTC', 'USD', 9999, time_delta)` in your first code, without changing the function. does it make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes a lot of sense. Thanks, really appreciate your help. Learned a great deal :)

Comment: Hi, I got one more question: The maximum length seems to be set to about 24h. I played around with the limit value, removed this limitation entirely, added "all_data=True", all without success.Do you have an idea how I would be able to get a timestamp.min() of 10 or 20 months back or even set a simple start date? This is the the portion I changed:

Comment: def minute_price_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol, aggregate, exchange='', all_data=True):
    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym={}&tsym={}&&aggregate={}'\
            .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper(), aggregate)

Comment: https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#-api-data-histominute-    That one says something about a 7 day limiation at least if I understand that correctly

Comment: @FatTwin here the parameter `all_data` you add to your function `minute_price_historical` is not use in the definition of your url, so it is not take into account. But anyway, I don't hink it would work as this is not a parameters of of the historyminute request. You have the parameter `allData` when you do historyday request.

Comment: @FatTwin I'm not an expert with these requests but what you want to do about the historyminute 10 months ago does not seem available as they say something about 7 days buffer for minute history, although I'm ot sure how to access it. Finally, It seems that you can get all the data (one per day) since a long time but you need to change the url definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171870/discussion-between-ben-t-and-fattwin).